# LinkedIn Batch comment api

Tags: linkedin-api

curl -X GET 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/{shareUrn|ugcPostUrn|commentUrn}/comments?ids=List({commentId})' 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {INSERT_TOKEN}'

**I had put shareUrn with multiple commentIds and single comment of that post,but it throws internal server error**